# Arabic Language is not getting render properly in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css

Arabic Language is not rendering properly in Internet Explorer 11, but it is rendering correctly in Google Chrome and Firefox.

I have tried the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.ex1 {
    direction: rtl;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>Some text. Default writing direction.</div>
<div class="ex1">
<br>
{ Some text. Right-to-left direction.
<br>
{ Some text. Right-to-left direction.
<br>
{ Some text. Right-to-left direction.
<br>
{ Some text. Right-to-left direction.
<br>    

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that IE 11 has a problem with the text breaks.

If you wrap each line in its own div it works fine.

```
<div>Some text. Default writing direction.</div>
<div class="ex1">
  <div>
    { Some text. Right-to-left direction.
  </div>
  <div>
    { Some text. Right-to-left direction.
  </div>
  <div>
    { Some text. Right-to-left direction.
  </div>
  <div>
    { Some text. Right-to-left direction.
  </div>
  <div>
    { Some text. Right-to-left direction.
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqy3z1rs/1/)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `<bdi>` or `<bdo>`tags? It's designed for text like Arabic that goes the opposite direction.

I'm not sure the exact placement you need for everything, but here is a great resource for using them correctly:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_bdo.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_bdi.asp

I think in this case you want bdo. Here's a snippet. Let me know if there are issues. I tried in JSFiddle in Browserstack to emulate IE11 and it did seem to work nicely!

```css
.ex1 {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text. Default writing direction.</div>
<div class="ex1">
<br>
<bdo>{</bdo> Some text. Right-to-left direction.
<br>
<bdo>{</bdo> Some text. Right-to-left direction.
<br>
<bdo>{</bdo> Some text. Right-to-left direction.
```